# Sending html to printer in C#

Tags: c#, html, gwt, printing, printers

I have html that needs to be printed on client side. I just want to know the procedure to send that html to printer printing 2 copies of it in C#.

I have a web app made in Google web toolkit and java and uses Container(WebView) built in C# to  render it. Here i want 2 copies of html(available on client side) to be be printed. So what i am thinking is to pass html to Webview(C#) and it will send the html to printer , printing 2 copies without any dialog coming up on way.

Another thing that i can do is to pass link which returns html to be printed to Webview as Html file can be very long to be pass .Now Webview can use that link and retrieve html and send it to printer.

So Please tell me the procedure of printing in this way.
Also I want to print exactly 2 copies that too without any dialog.